# How does SpringBoot deserialize JSON, and when does it do it?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I'm currently working on a SpringBoot API to interface with a MongoRepository, but I'm having trouble understanding how the JSON being passed becomes a Document for storage within Mongo. I currently have a simple API that stores a group of users:

```
@Document
@JsonInclude
public class Group {

    @Id
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String id;

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String name;

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private Set<GroupMember> groupMembers = new HashSet<>();
}
```

There are also setter and getter methods for each of the fields, although I don't know how necessary those are either (see questions at the end).

Here is the straightforward component I'm using:

```
@Component
@Path("/groups")
@Api(value = "/groups", description = "Group REST")
public class Groups {

    @Autowired
    private GroupService groupService;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get all Groups", response = Group.class, responseContainer = "List")
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    public List<Group> getAllGroups() {
        return groupService.getAllGroups();
    }

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Create a Group", response = Group.class)
    @JsonView(Views.Detailed.class)
    public Group submitGroup(Group group) {
        return groupService.addGroup(group);
    }
}
```

Finally, I have a Service class:

```
@Service
public class GroupServiceImpl implements GroupService {

    @Autowired
    private GroupRepository groupRepository;

    @Override
    public Group addGroup(Group group) {
        group.setId(null);
        return groupRepository.save(group);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Group> getAllGroups() {
        return groupRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

The `GroupRespository` is simply an interface which extends `MongoRepository<Group,String>`

Now, when I actually make a call to the `POST` method, with a body containing:

```
{
    "name": "group001",
    "groupMembers": []
}
```

I see that it properly inserts this group with a random Mongo UUID. However, if I try to insert `GroupMember` objects inside the list, I receive a null pointer exception. From this, I have two questions:

1. How does SpringBoot (Jackson?) know which fields to deserialize from the JSON being passed? I tested this after deleting the getter and setter methods, and it still works.
2. How does SpringBoot handle nested objects, such as the Set inside the class? I tested with `List` instead of `Set`, and it worked, but I have no idea why. My guess is that for each object that is both declared in my class and listed in my JSON object, SpringBoot is calling a constructor that it magically created behind the scenes, and one doesn't exist for the Set interface.
3. Suppose I'm adamant on using `Set` (the same user shouldn't show up twice anyway). What tools can I use to get SpringBoot to work as expected?

It seems to me that a lot of the things that happen in Spring are very behind-the-scenes, which makes it difficult for me to understand why things work when they do. Not knowing why things work makes it difficult to construct things from scratch, which makes it feel as though I'm hacking together a project rather than actually engineering one. So my last question is something like, is there a guide that explains the wiring behind the scenes?

Finally, this is my first time working with Spring... so please excuse me if my questions are entirely off the mark, but I would appreciate any answers nonetheless.

Comment: Spring and SpringBoot do a LOT for the Java Developer.  If you are familiar with Java development already, I would recommend starting with vanilla Spring, and avoid SpringBoot until you have a better grasp of Java development with Spring.  Here is the current Spring documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/